# Content updated on CM site is not visible without Publish

Tags: publishing, content-management

We have upgraded one application from **7.2 to 8.2** version. The application is hosted on **separate CM and CD** servers across different network zones. As per my understanding, if any record is added/edited to the CM server (Content tree) and save, it should be reflected to CM site without publishing. But we need to publish the added/edited content to reflect it on CM site. Is anything specific configuration is to be done to achieve this. or it is expected behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to publish the item to see it on CM server as not logged in user.

You can skip publishing on CM by configuring CM to run in Sitecore Live Mode.

The shortest answer how you can do this is find your site definition and set `database` property to use `master` instead of `web`. When you do this, all the changes made in Content or Experience Editor will be reflected automatically in the CM website.

More to read:

- http://sitecore-masters.com/en/sitecore-live-mode/
- https://www.techguilds.com/blog/2017/07/enabling-sitecores-live-mode